# Ads crash on loading android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, ads

I had google ads inside my app.They  used to work fine before i added facebook(audience) ads too.What i do is when ad facebook ad fails to load i show google ad. My ads used towork fine but until yesterday they started crashing the app with error

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.zzc.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpx.zzP(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfa.zzS(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfa.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.bison.multipurposeapp.fragments.BaseTabLayoutFragment.requestNewInterstitial(BaseTabLayoutFragment.java:127)
                                                                      at com.bison.multipurposeapp.fragments.BaseTabLayoutFragment.loadInterstitial(BaseTabLayoutFragment.java:164)
                                                                      at com.bison.multipurposeapp.fragments.BaseTabLayoutFragment$1.onError(BaseTabLayoutFragment.java:91)
                                                                      at com.facebook.ads.AdView$1.a(Unknown Source)
```

This is the piece of code;

```
  private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(Constants.ADMOB_TESTING_DEVICE_LENOVO)
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);//here the app crashes
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize Google Ads with null `Context`.

Comment: thanks man.i ll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you are passing null context to the ad request.If you are using fragment instead of passing `getActivity(`) pass the context received in `onAttach();`